# Auto layout with custom textfield

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield

I set my auto layout correctly, and it works. However, when I use a custom UITextField class in landscape orientation, the border isn't changed. I use the following code:

```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: (NSCoder!)) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate=self;
        border.borderColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xc6c6c6).cgColor

        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //self.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: CGFloat(23))
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)



    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)


    }
```

How should I do to change my custom border size when orientation is changed.

Comment: how is this code related to autolayout?

Comment: Furthermore, do you have an image of the portrait mode and landscape mode to see the difference?

Comment: Excuse me. The problem is from the border not auto layout. When I change orientation, my custom border width won't be modified.

Comment: Check your orientation from either the controller (viewWIllLayoutSubviews or viewWillTransitionTo(size:)) or the view (layoutSubviews). Depending on the view bounds, code what you need.

Comment: @dfd could you please explain to me what should I do? I'm a new programmer in iphon ;)

Comment: I pretty much gave you what you need. With an understanding of the view lifecycle along with what is triggered when orientation changes - that's the functions/methods I gave you, check view bounds (it's height and width) to determine the orientation. Based on that, change the border. (Of course, for many things - maybe not this though - you can use auto layout, along with size and trait classes).

Comment: I needed to go offline for a bit. I'll try to post a good explanation with some code shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app of mine has a need to change constraints when orientation changes. While you **can** use size classes and trait collections, my needs went beyond that.

Size classes work very well most times, stack controls work pretty well too, but I needed to maximize a GLKView as much as possible and thus, move 4 sliders from the bottom (in portrait) to the right (in landscape). If you use size classes **and** code a universal app you'll quickly learn that iPads have "normal" size no matter what the orientation is.

Here's how I've coded this app to check what orientation it is in.

First, I extended UIView:

```
extension UIView {
    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

In my view controller I have the following:

```
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            // place your orientation change code here - isInPortrait will indicate which orientation the device is in
        }
    }
}
```

I find that viewWillLayoutSubviews() is the best spot for me, as it's hit initially, and every time orientation changes. There are other places too - viewDidLayoutSubviews() and viewWillTransistionTo(size:) in particular - but the WWDC talk about **Making Apps Adaptive Part 2** used this also. Besides, you now have all view sizes you need!

The key thing to remember is that viewWIllLayoutSubviews() may get called a few times during app startup and/or orientation change, so you need to code for it. Making two Bool variables takes care of that, and your code will only run once.